# how to write an onDragEnd function to make dnd work

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

There is a Main component, which contains 4 components that need to move
I understand that when the position changes, the index of the component should change
I don't understand how to make the components stay in the places where they were moved (If necessary, I can make the code in codesandbox)

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import CardWeather from '../cardWeather/CardWeather';
import WeatherMap from '../cardWeatherMap/WeatherMap';
import Forecast from '../forecast/Forecast';
import WeatherGrapth from '../weatherGraph/WeatherGraph';
import './main.scss';
import { DragDropContext, Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

const Main = () => {

  const [components, setComponents] = useState([{
    components: {
      'component-1': {id: 'comp-1'},
      'component-2': {id: 'comp-2'},
      'component-3': {id: 'comp-3'},
      'component-4': {id: 'comp-4'},
    }
  }
  ])

  const onDragEnd = (result) => {
    const { destination, source } = result
    console.log(result)
    if (!destination) {
      return
    }
    if (
      destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
      destination.index === source.index
    ) {
      return
    }
    
  }


    return (
<>
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}> 
      <Droppable droppableId="main">
        {
          (provided) => (
            <div className="main-container"
            ref={provided.innerRef} 
            {...provided.droppableProps}
            >
              <CardWeather />              
              <Forecast/>
              <WeatherGrapth/>
              <WeatherMap/>
              {provided.placeholder}
        </div>
          )
        }
      </Droppable>
        <div className="pr">weather app</div>
        </DragDropContext>
        </>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't manage to solve it, you simply need to rearrange the components state.

It seems meaningless to initialize your state like so (array of an object of objects(?)) considering the fact you are managing only one state in this component, which is an array of objects.
So your state should be [{cmp: 'cmp1', id(?): 'comp-1'},{cmp: 'cmp2', id?: 'comp-2'}, etc...].

In any way, onDragEnd you get result which contains destination, source, type, and draggableId.
Find the dragged component (components.find(cmp => cmp.id === draggableId)), create a copy of the original array, splice the source.index, and insert the dragged component in the destination.index.

It should look something like that:

```
const onDragEnd = ({destination, source, type, draggableId}: DropResult) =>  {
  if (!destination) {
    return
  }

  const draggedCmp = components.find(cmp => cmp.id === draggableId)
  if (!draggedCmp) {
    return
  }      

  const newCmps = [...components]
  newCmps.splice(source.index, 1)
  newCmps.splice(destination.index, 0, draggedCmp)

  setComponents(newCmps)
```